# Issues getting my DIV container to center

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my Div container with my images to center. I tried margin 0 auto; and adding a width.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 }

.main{
 height: 950px;
 background:  url(../Images/Mountain.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat; 
 }

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px;){
 #container{
 height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
 }

.header{
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 }

.logo{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 } 

nav{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 26px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 }

.navBar{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.navBar:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
 }

span{
 width: 100%;
 }

h1{
 font-size: 80px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 200px;
 }

h2{
 font-size: 36px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both;
 margin-top: 50px;
 }

/*Header Section*/

#head{
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/6934/beach-vacation-water-summer.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat; 
 }

.port{
 padding-top: 75px;
 }

.portfolio{
 width: 300px;
 height: 250px;
 }

.padding{
   margin-left: 50px;
 }
.container_port{
 width: 1000px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>-------</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="text/css" href="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="head">
  <div class="header">
   <img class="logo" src=http://placehold.it/100x100>

   <nav>
    <a class="navBar" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="navBar" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="navBar" href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="navBar" href="#">Testimonials</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <span>
   <h1 class="port">Portfolio</h1>
  </span>

 </div> 
 <div id="container_port">

   <div class="one">
    <img class="portfolio" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
   </div>
   <div class="two">
    <img class="portfolio" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
   </div>
   <div class="three">
    <img class="portfolio" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
   </div>
   <div class="four">
    <img class="portfolio" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <img class="portfolio padding" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
   </div>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
#container_port {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:**  I also just noticed that you have `.container_port` in your CSS above while it's clearly an ID and not a CLASS.

Comment: Thank you much! That worked out perfectly, as for the ID and CLASS that was and accident when I was transferring everything!

Comment: Glad to help!  Would you mind accepting the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the image element is an inline-block element. You could change it to a block-level element or you could use margin: 0 50%;